# Kotlin `apply()` method analog in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I would like to be able to do something like `apply()` from Kotlin in Dart. For example in Kotlin

```
var userDetails: UserDetails = userRepo.getUser().apply{
    //here 'this' is UserDetails so all the further calls are made in that context
    name = "Name"
    email = "email@test.com"
    callSomeInnerMethodOfUserDetails()
};
```

Is there some similar method or way to do it in Dart language?

I want to know whether there are some things in standard library or language itself, rather than my own generic closure extension for such a purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While there is no exact analog I stumbled upon a peculiar operator called [Cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-) that does similar job.

The given example will look something like:

```
UserDetails userDetails = userRepo.getUser()
    ..name = 'Name'
    ..email = 'email@test.com'
    ..callSomeInnerMethodOfUserDetails();
```

You can also do a nested cascade also

```
UserDetails otherUserDetails = userRepo.getUser()
    ..name = (userRepo.getUser()
              ..firstName= "Other Name"
              ..assignFirstNameAndSurnameToNameField()).name
    ..email = "otherEmail"
    ..callSomeInnerMethodOfUserDetails();
```

Hope it helps.